# Python: ICD-10 RegEx

Tags: python-3.x, regex, icd

Goal: create regex of **ICD-10 codes**.

##### Format

- Compulsory start: `Letter`, `Digit`, (either `Letter` or `Digit`),
- Optional end: has a `.` then up to 4 Letters or Digits

I've most of the 1st half:

```py
r'[A-Z][0-9][0-9]'
```

The second half I'm stuck on:

```py
([a-z]|[0-9]){1,4}$
```

If there is something generated, it must have a dot `.`

Examples: `.0` or `.A9` or `.A9A9` or `.ZZZZ` or `.9999` etc.

---

[Test Python RegEx](https://regex101.com/)

Note: I know some ICD-10 codes don't surpass a certain number/ letter; but I am fine with this.

Comment: `^[A-Za-z][0-9][a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4})?$`? See https://regex101.com/r/s4DFEN/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z0-9](?:\.[A-Z0-9]{1,4})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s4DFEN/3). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `[0-9]` - an ASCII only digit
- `[A-Z0-9]` - an uppercase ASCII letter or an ASCII digit
- `(?:\.[A-Z0-9]{1,4})?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[A-Z0-9]{1,4}` - one to four occurrences of an uppercase ASCII letter or an ASCII digit
- `$` - end of string anchor (or `\Z` can be used here, too).

In Python code, you can use the following to validate string input:

```py
icd10_rx = re.compile(r'[A-Z][0-9][A-Z0-9](?:\.[A-Z0-9]{1,4})?')
if icd10_rx.fullmatch(text):
    print(f'{text} is valid!')
```

Note the anchors are left out because [`Pattern.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.fullmatch) (same as [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch)) requires a full string match.